# Angular view not updating properly on ng-click

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, twitter-bootstrap-2

Im writing selecting button menu and when I try to get to next select level nothing happens.

In first list item i want to write selected value from next level, in second I have successfully listed all items from first level and in third I want to display second (last) level oprions.

My code looks like:

```
    <div ng-if="selected.type=='number' && selected.values[0].values">
            <ul class="smsUl">
                <li ng-if="selected.selected">
                    <button class="btn btn-warning btn-block">{{selected.selected}}</button>
                </li>
                <li ng-repeat="value in selected.values" ng-if="attributes == undefined">
                    <button class="btn btn-info btn-block" ng-click="$parent.attributes=value.values">{{value.value}}</button>
                </li>
                <li ng-repeat="attribut in attributes" ng-if="attributes != undefined">
                    <button class="btn btn-info btn-block" ng-click="selected.value=attribut.id; selected.selected=attribut.value; attributes=undefined">{{attribut.value}}</button>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

And part of jason with selected.values looks like:

```
  [
  {
    "value": "clothing_glasses",
    "values": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "value": "coat"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "value": "glasses"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "value": "book_stationery",
    "values": [
      {
        "id": 3,
        "value": "book"
      },
      {
        "id": 4,
        "value": "document"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

In nf-if expression I tried with:

```
!attributes
```

but nothing has changed.

### Update:

If I set attribute variable  in controller staticly it lists the content I want, but if I select, i should go back to the 1. level.

Comment: Try using Angular Batarang or ng-inspector to make sure that the $parent is in fact the parent you are expecting.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are not doing something like this in controller:

```
$scope.attributes = [someArray]

(bla bla, some code)

$scope.someOnClickFunction = function() {
    $scope.attributes = [otherArray]
}
```

if so, than you are losing scope of the correct variable, and angular no longer watches what you think it should.

I reccomend creating some object called eg. "observable", put there all those 'attributes', 'selected' etc, and add to your controller:

```
$scope.$watchCollection('observable.attributes', function() {});
$scope.$watchCollection('observable.selected', function() {});
```

and when you want to change something in those arrays dont replace them (by applying new arrays to old variable).
If you dont want to play with pushgin, shifting, poping elements you can always use:

```
someDefinedArray.length = 0;
for-loop {
    someDefinedArray.push(yoursobjects); //push objects back to array but with changes you wanted to make to array
}
```

Comment: I solved it using $parent.$parent.something, my tpl file had nested foerach loops, so I left my original $scope behind.